# How to get Projective coordinates using spongy castle in Android

Tags: android, cryptography, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I am able to generate Public key and Private key using spongy castle in Android by using the following code

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
ECGenParameterSpec ecSpecCurve163k1 = new ECGenParameterSpec("sect163r2"); // Curve: B-163
keyGen.initialize(ecSpecCurve163k1);
aKeyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
String pubStr = Crypto.base64Encode(aKeyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
String privStr = Crypto.base64Encode(aKeyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
```

I get Affine coordinates by using the following code

```
PublicKey otherKey // key generated by the code above
ECPublicKey ecPubKey = (ECPublicKey) otherKey;
Log.d("public key Wx", ecPubKey.getW().getAffineX().toString(16));
Log.d("public key Wy", ecPubKey.getW().getAffineY().toString(16));
```

I am trying to get the projective coordinates for the above coordinates by using spongy castle. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: I have found somethind from [link](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Elliptic-curve-query-td4310337.html) which is available for bouncy castle. But again class EC Proj Point is not available under spongy castle. Any idea?

Comment: Going from affine coordinates to the usual projective coordinates is trivial: (x,y) --> (x,y,1).

Comment: @GregS well mathematicaly is not such a big problem. Although I have no idea how to implement this by having the above informations.. Do you have any idea or any implemented source code?

Comment: Can I do in the following Way?

X_projCord = ecPubKey.getW().getAffineX();